# Android Studio: Checkout transparente Mercado Pago

Tags: android-studio

Estou tentando integrar pela primeira vez o checkout transparente para Android do MercadoPago.

Já baixei e coloquei pra funcionar no Emulador a versão mais recente do aplicativo em https://github.com/mercadopago/px-android.

Na página GitHub acima, é explicado como integrar o checkout transparente do MercadoPago com apenas uma linha de código.

```
new MercadoPagoCheckout.Builder("public_key", "checkout_preference_id")
    .build()
    .startPayment(activityOrContext, requestCode);
```

Onde `public_key` nós conseguimos na página de credenciais do MercadoPago. Mas a **String** `checkout_preference_id` eu não sei como criar, mesmo embora quase no final da página GitHub tenha um modelo de como criá-la.

**Create your preference id**

```
curl -X POST \
     'https://api.mercadopago.com/checkout/preferences?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d '{
           "items": [
               {
               "title": "Dummy Item",
               "description": "Multicolor Item",
               "quantity": 1,
               "currency_id": "ARS",
               "unit_price": 10.0
               }
           ],
           "payer": {
               "email": "payer@email.com"
           }
     }'
```

Tentei colocar uma **String** qualquer em `checkout_preference_id`, mas não funcionou. Apenas funcionou a **String** fornecida no próprio exemplo do aplicativo do GitHub:

```
private static final String DUMMY_PREFERENCE_ID = "243962506-0bb62e22-5c7b-425e-a0a6-c22d0f4758a9";
```

Todas as outras formas de implementar apresentadas no aplicativo exemplo exigem uma resposta fake de confirmação de pagamento.

Devido a minha pouca experiência com desenvolvimento de aplicativos, eu não tenho idéia de como criar e passar essa variável.

Agradeço se alguém puder ajudar a criar e passar a variável `checkout_preference_id`.

**EDITADO**

Também agradeceria muito se alguém pudesse resolver o problema de **confirmação de pagamento falso**, exemplificando com código.

Eu acho que `checkout_preference_id` pode ser acessado via Marketplace em um site ou talvez ao criar uma `curl` usando webservice do Android. Então, essa parte ainda é um mistério pra mim.

Com relação ao modo alternativo de criar um pagamento com MercadoPago, temos outros argumentos para passar:

```
new MercadoPagoCheckout.Builder("public_key", checkoutPreference, paymentConfiguration)
                .build()
                .startPayment(activityOrContext, requestCode);
```

Onde `checkoutPreference` nos permite criar um **item personalizado** para vender.

```
final Item item = new Item.Builder("Product Title", 1, new BigDecimal(12.3)).setDescription("Product Description").build();
CheckoutPreference checkoutPreference = new CheckoutPreference.Builder(Sites.BRASIL, "a@a.a", Collections.singletonList(item)).setDefaultInstallments(1).build();
```

`paymentConfiguration` é onde a **confirmação de pagamento false** é implementado.

```
PaymentConfiguration paymentConfiguration = new PaymentConfiguration.Builder(new MyPaymentProcessor()).build();
```

Onde a classe `MyPaymentProcessor()` e outras classes na qual ela depende pode ser encontrada no exemplo do GitHub.

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema. Já conseguiu solucionar?

Comment: Ainda não! Até agora só consegui implementar uma **resposta falsa de pagamento**, o que já está exemplificado no aplicativo oferecido no GitHub. Já vasculhei a internet, enviei e-mail pro suporte do MercadoPago e enviei perguntas para a [comunidade do MercadoPago](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!categories/mercadopago-developers-brasil/sdks) e até agora nada.

Comment: Parece-me que o segredo é a primeira etapa, criar um servidor para se comunicar com o servidor do Mercado Pago para pegar a preference_id. O que me parece estranho.

Comment: Fiz um pequeno teste. Fiz uma requisição POST do pagamento, como tem https://github.com/mercadopago/px-android e com a resposta tem uma tag "id", coloquei no checkout_preference_id  e funcionou.

Comment: Se for possível, poderia postar um exemplo de código de como realizar essa tarefa? Qual método você usou para fazer a requisição, **Volley**?

Comment: Se o problema é com suporte da API, deve consultar o fornecedor da mesma diretamente. Se for algo no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic), é importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena entender [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e ler o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).